# Can't use an external DLL : FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, dll, filenotfoundexception

I have 2 projects.
The first one just generates a DLL.

The second one needs the first DLL.
But when I call a method from the DLL, I have a FileNotFoundException, with this message :

BDD, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

I'm sure that the file exists.
Where I'm wrong ?

Comment: Have you added the DLL as a reference in the project that is trying to use it? Or at least copied the DLL into the same directory as the compiled executable?

Comment: Is the project1.dll in the same folder as the project2.exe when you run it?

Comment: What's the name of the Project/Assembly ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agree with Kieren (+1). Maybe it is finding your DLL but it requires another dependent DLL that cannot be found. Or is there a signature issue (maybe you are looking for another DLL version, etc...)
To turn on fusion Log (you'll have to create a couple fo registry keys):
[image: Set LogFailures to 0/1 to disable/enable]

BTW, fusion is the DLL that contains the logic to load an assembly (probing for local path and subfolders if specified, looking at the GAC, ...). After running your executable, you'll find a log detailing the issues the CLR has found when loading referenced assemblies (ignore the NativeImage logs, inspect just the Default logs).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: The DLL needs to be in the same directory as the EXE.

Is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

Could you give the full message - and:

Please bear in mind that the `FileNotFoundException` could be for a *dependency* of the referenced DLL, not just the referenced DLL itself.

You might want to turn on assembly-binding log (Fusion log) to see what's going on, if the DLL is indeed present.

Comment: I think you need to provide info on how to turn on that log.

Comment: I import the DLL to VisualStudio, without problem.
But when I call a method from the DLL, I receive the filenotfound...

Comment: You can't 'import' a DLL, do you mean add a reference?  That doesn't necessarily mean much.  Perhaps you could answer the questions people are asking - what's the full error, is the DLL in the same directory as the executable, etc?

Comment: Yes the the DLL is in the same directory.
Full Error : http://pastebin.com/zpZgJfMf

Comment: Lines 18 through 21 are saying 'attempting to download DLL from URL..' and it's looking in `/bin/debug/BDD.DLL` but not finding it.  Is the DLL *definitely* at the correct location, `C:/IHMAdministrateur/IHMAdministrateur/bin/Debug/BDD.DLL` ?